# Get value from mutiple tags xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

Using the following XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Subjects>
  <Subject>
    <Title>Mr</Title>
    <Firstname></Firstname>
    <Surname></Surname>
    <Email></Email>
    <Incidents>
      <Incident>
        <ReferenceNo>meuen</ReferenceNo>
      </Incident>
    </Incidents>
    <TelephoneNos />
    <Employers />
    <BankAccounts />
  </Subject>
  <Subject>
    <Title>Mr</Title>
    <Firstname>Test</Firstname>
    <Surname>Test</Surname>
    <Email>test@test.com</Email>
    <Incidents>
      <Incident>
        <ReferenceNo>jkcsdlkjsdl</ReferenceNo>
      </Incident>
    </Incidents>
    <TelephoneNos />
    <Employers />
    <BankAccounts />
  </Subject>
</Subjects>
```

I want to extract all the ```ReferenceNo` tags and represent like this:

```
<RefNos>
   <RefNo>meuen</RefNo>
   <RefNo>jkcsdlkjsdl</RefNo>
</RefNos>
```

I have tried using the below XSLT:

```
<RefNos>
                <xsl:for-each select="(//*[local-name() ='ReferenceNo'][text()])">
                    <xsl:variable name="incidentNumbers" select="(//*[local-name() ='ReferenceNo'])"/>
                    <RefNo>
                        <xsl:value-of select="$incidentNumbers[text()]"/>
                    </RefNo>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </RefNos>
```

But this only gets the first populated item in the XML, if the top tag is empty it will only have the value of the bottom tag, and vice versa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A path that starts with `//` is an absolute path that selects all descendants of the document root node. So your variable always contains all `ReferenceNo` nodes in the entire XML document, regardless of what the current `ReferenceNo` node is. And in XSLT 1.0 the `xsl:value-of` instruction returns only the value of the first node in the selected node-set.

If you change the variable to contain only the current `ReferenceNo` node:

```
<xsl:variable name="incidentNumbers" select="."/>
```

it will work as you expect.

---

Of course, this is all grossly over-complicated. There is no need for the variable, and - above all - it should never be necessary to resort to a hack like:

```
*[local-name() ='ReferenceNo']
```

Also, it is preferable to use explicit paths instead of `//`. For example:

```
<xsl:template match="/Subjects">
    <RefNos>
        <xsl:for-each select="Subject">
            <RefNo>
                <xsl:value-of select="Incidents/Incident/ReferenceNo"/>
            </RefNo>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </RefNos>
</xsl:template>
```

should work well in this case.

Answer (score 1):

To select all `ReferenceNo` elements, simply use `//ReferenceNo`. To transform each of them to a `RefNo` element use

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <RefNos>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="//ReferenceNo"/>
  </RefNos>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ReferenceNo">
  <RefNo>
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </RefNo>
</xsl:template>
```